# I have and array inside the value of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an dictionary and the value containts the array of string as follows

```
arr = ["key":"["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]"]
```

I want the new array to be like

```
let array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
```

How to parse it

Comment: `let array = arr["key"]`

Comment: arr is a dictionary, not an array so no need for [0]

Comment: @Anbu.karthik It is not array !! Closing !!

Comment: ya got it, sry I am not clearly seen the ?

Comment: is the array in the top line contained within a String?

Answer (score 1):

You can access dictionary items in few different ways, the easiest is:

```
let array = arr["key"]
```

You may need to conditionally unwrap it

```
if let array = arr["key"] as? [String] {
   // rest of code with array
}
```